# Spring Boot Security : java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I created a blank project, added one controller with one method to print hello.
The URL is: **http://localhost:8080/hello/abc**

```
package com.test.security.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
    public String sayHello(@PathVariable("name") String name){
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

I added following dependency and I can see login form.

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    ...
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I entered username/password as **user** / **whatever-printed-in-console**
Something like this as password: **3f6d06f6-2936-4c88-aaee-c8f125e91663**

User is authenticated and on the next page, I see a big stack trace
Something like this:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2953)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2432)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
...
...
```

I can edit this to provide full stack trace if required but I did not find anything special. 
I tried to search multiple posts on this but for them, this happened with their custom config.

I added no config at this moment.

What is wrong here?

**Edit**

These two lines are repeating in stack trace

```
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:582)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:241)
```

Comment: Have you added spring security configuration? I mean have  you configured spring security? Add full  stack trace.

Comment: Stacktrace is huge, but I edited my post for more clarity. No, I did not configure spring security and just added the dependency

Comment: Have you configured view resolver? Just change `@Controller` to `@RestController`. Because if you configured view resolver, then `@RestController`  is required instead of `@Controller`

Comment: Thanks a lot @PraveenKumarLalasangi, that was a big mistake from me. Changing to RestController fixed that. It was looking for view before that. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think you have searched lot of questions. Is there any where this problem is mentioned? If not i will consider writing answer, becuase visitor will only look for answer, but not comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to send String response from controller method either you use

```java
@GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
public @ResponseBody String sayHello(@PathVariable("name") String name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Or

```java
@GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
@ResponseBody
public String sayHello(@PathVariable("name") String name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

Or use `@RestController` for your controller class instead of `@Controller`

**So why stack overflow error**

> **From Doc**
>   controller normally returns a logical view name

So return string is used to construct URL and new request is constructed with the new request path. Here new request again will have same base path and again it reaches the same method and again it repeats the same method, repeating infinitely resulting in stack overflow error.

Just have look at code and debug logs which gives you the clear idea and it is  self explained

```java
@GetMapping("/hello/{name}")
public String sayHello(@PathVariable("name") String name, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Request URL: "+request.getRequestURL());
    System.out.println("name: "+name);
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

and logs goes here

```
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/praveen
name: praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello praveen
name: Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
-----------------------------------------
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/jwt/hello/Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
name: Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello praveen
```